# Kimono Labs takes forever to create API

Tags: json, api, html

When I try to create an API from a webpage using Kimono Lab, it takes forever to create it(it's stuck on the create api screen).
[image]

I've tried using the google chrome extension but it yields the same problem. I also cleared my cookies and browsing data but it still won't work.
Any reasons why it's not working.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue and thought that it wasn't working, but I happened to let it sit there while I grabbed dinner and over 2 hours later, it actually worked and created my API.

I have verified that it takes a long time using both Chrome and Firefox, the extension and bookmarklet. Not sure why it takes that long, but try just letting it go for a while.